# Increase user interaction with plots

Tags: core-plot

When I touch on a line plot in my multiline plot graph, the method for displaying a symbol with values corresponding to the point is not called frequently,

```
-(void)scatterPlot:(CPTScatterPlot *)plot plotSymbolWasSelectedAtRecordIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
```

This problem is also with barplots. plotSymbolMarginForHitDetection property also set to high value. But No effect. How can I increase my graph's user interaction?

Comment: Not called frequently, or not at all? Did you set the plot delegate?

Comment: The delegate method get called, but I need to identify every touches on the line plot and the delegate method should invoked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no scatter plot delegate method for detecting hits on the line between plot points. If that's what you're after, you'll need to use a plot space delegate. Handle the touch event and look through the plot data to find which line segment (if any) is near the touched point.

Bar plots aren't as complicated. Any touch inside a bar should trigger the delegate method. You might have issues if the bars are very narrow. The only solution in that case is to make them wider.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to increase your "hit area" is to monitor all touches in your graph and translate that to the closest index.

To do this, you'll have to make sure the delegate is nil (since you are manually monitoring).

```
self.myBarPlot.delegate = nil;
```

Then, on your `CPTGraphHostingView`, set up your `UIGestureRecognizers`. I've found that using both tap and pan recogizners works best. Set these up like so.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(graphTapped:)];
[self.hostView addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];

UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(graphPanned:)];
[self.hostView addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];
```

The recognizers will monitor when your hostView has been tapped or panned. From there, you can easily translate the location of the touch to an index doing the following.

```
- (void)graphTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        [self gestureUpdated:sender];
    }
}

- (void)graphPanned:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded || sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
        [self gestureUpdated:sender];
    }
}

- (void)gestureUpdated:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    CGFloat width = self.hostView.frame.size.width;
    CGPoint loc = [sender locationInView:self.hostView];
    NSInteger index = (loc.x / width) * [self numberOfRecordsForPlot:self.myBarPlot];
    NSLog(@"Touch index: %li", index);
}
```

Now that we have an index, just go ahead and do what you did in your original delegate callback.

For bar plots:

```
[self barPlot:self.myBarPlot barWasSelectedAtRecordIndex:index];
```

For scatter plots (untested):

```
[self scatterPlot:self.myScatterPlot plotSymbolWasSelectedAtRecordIndex:index];
```

Violà!